# Issue with inverse fourier transforms using fftw

Tags: c++, fft, fftw

I am using the library fftw3 to perform discrete fourier transforms. I have an array of real values and my process is as follows
input_vals -> fourier transform -> out_vals -> inverse_fourier -> input_vals -> fourier transform -> out_vals_2

by this logic, out_vals_2 should have the same value as out_vals (maybe scaled or something but this is not the case.

```cpp
void fill_vals(std::vector<double>& vec);
int main() {
    std::vector<double> in_vals;
    std::vector<double> in_vals_2;
    in_vals.resize(100 * 100);
    in_vals_2.resize(100 * 100);
    std::vector<std::complex<double>> out_vals;
    std::vector<std::complex<double>> out_vals_2;

    out_vals.resize(100 * 51);
    out_vals_2.resize(100 * 51); // fftw only needs half of the 2nd dim since hermitian symmetry
    fftw_plan p = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(100, 100, in_vals.data(), reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(out_vals.data()), FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fill_vals(in_vals);
    fftw_execute(p);
    fftw_plan p2 = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_2d(100, 100, reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(out_vals.data()),in_vals_2.data(), FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(p2);
    std::for_each(in_vals_2.begin(), in_vals_2.end(), [](double& n) { n *= 1e-4; });

    fftw_plan p3 = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(100, 100, in_vals_2.data(), reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(out_vals_2.data()), FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(p3);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 51; j++) {
            auto v1 = out_vals[j + i * 51];
            auto v2 = out_vals_2[j + i * 51];
            std::cout << "first: " << v1 << " second: " << v2 << std::endl;
        }  
    }
    fftw_destroy_plan(p);
    fftw_destroy_plan(p2);
    fftw_destroy_plan(p3);

}

void fill_vals(std::vector<double>& vec) {
    double dx = 0.1;
    double dy = 0.1;
    auto func = [](double x, double y) { return x * x + y * y; };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
            vec[j + i * 100] = func(i*dx, j*dy);
        }
    }
}
```

As you see, print the results of the first and second arrays of output values. I have verified that input_vals and input_vals_2 are the same except that input_vals_2 is scaled by a factor of 10^4 as expected.
I expected something similar for out_vals and out_vals_2 but here is a sample of the results I got

```
first: (2.90192e-09,5.92922e-09) second: (-7.04593e-13,3.38256e-13)
first: (-2.36417e-08,1.25076e-08) second: (-1.50865e-12,3.40183e-13)
first: (1.39576e-08,-1.31249e-08) second: (-5.03563e-13,-2.52082e-12)
first: (2.30798e-08,-1.90146e-08) second: (1.09575e-12,-1.5964e-12)
first: (-6.1091e-09,-2.94573e-09) second: (-1.44963e-12,-2.07039e-13)
first: (-1.28917e-08,1.48862e-09) second: (-4.04995e-13,-7.62142e-14)
first: (2.25352e-09,-4.84718e-09) second: (2.69047e-13,-1.20759e-12)
first: (-9.71393e-09,4.56817e-09) second: (4.55367e-13,-1.94835e-12)
first: (7.21847e-09,-5.33878e-09) second: (7.24309e-13,4.32916e-14)
first: (4.15668e-09,4.29824e-09) second: (2.31217e-13,4.0434e-13)
first: (1.37686e-08,-6.91411e-10) second: (7.21783e-13,-5.61445e-13)
first: (6.36243e-09,-1.1004e-08) second: (9.90841e-13,-3.4591e-13)
first: (-2.90555e-08,2.09318e-08) second: (-1.14937e-12,-2.00677e-12)
first: (-1.94677e-10,7.85383e-09) second: (-9.95736e-14,7.70894e-13)
first: (4.99992e-09,-1.01281e-08) second: (-3.27121e-13,-2.32422e-14)
first: (-8.02526e-09,-7.56433e-09) second: (-3.79182e-13,-2.91813e-13)
first: (1.09941e-08,-6.26367e-10) second: (1.4779e-12,-5.72337e-13)
first: (1.5862e-08,-9.53884e-09) second: (-3.96342e-13,2.11923e-14)
first: (-6.90393e-10,-1.38592e-08) second: (2.41286e-13,-1.54535e-13)
first: (4.06874e-09,1.25382e-08) second: (2.47501e-13,1.03788e-12)
first: (8.54262e-09,5.28323e-09) second: (9.61306e-13,9.28605e-13)
first: (4.74809e-09,1.22679e-08) second: (7.74782e-13,1.21958e-12)
first: (-4.14073e-08,-3.15596e-08) second: (-6.37816e-12,-8.50306e-13)
```

EDIT: I made a mistake with the indexing, here's the new output

Comment: Look at the size of your seconds.  They are all zero or really really close.  Are you sure you didn't lose the value along the way or do math or really big/small numbers and lose precision due to floating point round off?  It might also be useful to print the inverse and see if they match original.  It could the inverse that is failing.

Comment: I made sure that the inverse matched the original, so I know that part works

Comment: You have only shown a small part of the output. Show the largest values. The input signal created by `fill_vals` is atypical for signal processing. Maybe its DFT has a lot of small values, and they are getting swamped by the noise of rounding errors. Examining the largest values in the output would reveal that.